# How to Change Title Bar Height in Cocoa - Storyboard

Tags: cocoa, storyboard, height, titlebar

I am trying to change the title bar height in storyboard(Cocoa). I came across the INAppStore Window, which is not storyboard. How to adjust title bar height in storyboard(cocoa).

Answer (score 2):

I personally used WAYWindow and that worked pretty well but this will work just as well for INAppStoreWindow. It's a drop in replacement for NSWindow so you can select your window in your storyboard and then change its class to WAYWindow in the Identity inspector. After that you can go to the Attributes inspector and change the window height attribute.

You do need to be using an NSWindowController in your Storyboard though. If you use a "show" segue the view controller you segue to will be in a NSWindowController instance you can't change. If you want to have a  segue to a view controller where the window has a big title bar and you really don't want to segue to a window controller you would need to have a custom segue.

Comment: Thank You. I have tried WAYWindow as well, but i need a document based window in which the drop down for the save file should remain and want to display the toolbar as well. But it should be positioned vertically center and the toolbar and dropdown for save should display on the right side of it

Comment: If you need INAppStoreWindow because it works better for you, that's totally fine; you can use either with your storyboard. Are you still having trouble getting the title bar height to change?